# Log says that the autowire was done, but a NPE is thrown when the object is used

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to inject a DAO using @Autowire. Setting the log level to debug, I can see that the bean was created and wired to the service class, but, when I try to use the injected object, a nullpointerexecption is thrown.

English is not my primary language, but looking into the log bellow, it seems that the DAO was created and properly wired to the service:

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory:221 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ticketServiceImpl'
DefaultListableBeanFactory:450 - Creating instance of bean 'ticketServiceImpl'
InjectionMetadata:72 - Registered injected element on class [br.com.xpto.sys.business.impl.TicketServiceImpl]: AutowiredFieldElement for private br.com.xpto.sys.dao.api.TicketDAO br.com.xpto.sys.business.impl.TicketServiceImpl.dao
DefaultListableBeanFactory:523 - Eagerly caching bean 'ticketServiceImpl' to allow for resolving potential circular references
InjectionMetadata:86 - Processing injected element of bean 'ticketServiceImpl': AutowiredFieldElement for private br.com.xpto.sys.dao.api.TicketDAO br.com.xpto.sys.business.impl.TicketServiceImpl.dao
DefaultListableBeanFactory:221 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ticketDAOImpl'
DefaultListableBeanFactory:450 - Creating instance of bean 'ticketDAOImpl'
AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource:108 - Adding transactional method 'TicketDAOImpl.findByTicketNumber' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
InfrastructureAdvisorAutoProxyCreator:538 - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'ticketDAOImpl' with 0 common interceptors and 1 specific interceptors
JdkDynamicAopProxy:115 - Creating JDK dynamic proxy: target source is SingletonTargetSource for target object [br.com.xpto.sys.dao.impl.TicketDAOImpl@2242b3b8]
DefaultListableBeanFactory:478 - Finished creating instance of bean 'ticketDAOImpl'
AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:480 - Autowiring by type from bean name 'ticketServiceImpl' to bean named 'ticketDAOImpl'
DefaultListableBeanFactory:478 - Finished creating instance of bean 'ticketServiceImpl'
```

The NPE ocurrs into the dao.findByTicketId(ticketId) call. Since dao is null, it throws the exception.

I tried to do minor changes after that I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136886/spring-mvc3-2-2-hibernate4-autowire-sessionfactory-sessionfactory-gives-nul) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114050/spring-autowiring-dao-into-a-utility-class-not-working) posts, but with no lucky.

Below I posted the main parts of the code. Any advice is welcome.

**UPDATE**

As requested, I'm also posting how do I instantiate the TicketServiceImpl class and the stack trace.

The class is instantiated inside an ItemProcessor bean (spring batch)

```
public class TicketItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Ticket, TicketLog> {

    @Override
    public TicketLog process(Ticket item) throws Exception {

        TicketServiceImpl srv = new TicketServiceImpl();
        Ticket t = srv.findByTicketId(item.getIdTicket());

        return new TicketLog();
    }
}
```

**TicketServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class TicketServiceImpl implements TicketService {

    @Autowired
    private TicketDAO dao;

    @Override
    public Ticket findByTicketId(int ticketId) {
        return dao.findByTicketId(ticketId);
    }
}
```

**TicketDAOImpl**

```
@Repository
public class TicketDAOImpl extends implements TicketDAO {
    @Override
    public Ticket findByTicketId(int ticketId) {
        String jpql = "SELECT t FROM Ticket t WHERE t.id = :ticketId";

        Query query = getSession().createQuery(jpql);
        query.setParameter("ticketId", ticketId);
        query.setMaxResults(1);

        Object obj = query.uniqueResult();
        return (Ticket) obj;
    }
}
```

**TicketDAO**

```
public interface TicketDAO extends DAO<Ticket> {
    Ticket findByTicketId(int ticketId);
}
```

**DAO**

```
public interface DAO<E> extends Serializable {
    List<E> listAll();
}
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.xpto.sys" />

    <bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=db" />
        <property name="username" value="usr" />
        <property name="password" value="pwd" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dbDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.xpto.sys.model.entities" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">br.com.xpto.sys.dao.utils.SQLServerDialectOverrider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" mode="proxy"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
AbstractStep:222 - Encountered an error executing step step1 in job job-ProcessTickets
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.xpto.sys.business.impl.TicketServiceImpl.findByTicketId(TicketServiceImpl.java:83)
    at br.com.xpto.sys.jobs.spring.TicketItemProcessor.process(TicketItemProcessor.java:24)
    at br.com.xpto.sys.jobs.spring.TicketItemProcessor.process(TicketItemProcessor.java:1)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:293)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:192)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:395)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:141)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:151)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:130)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
    at br.com.xpto.sys.jobs.AppStandalone.run(AppStandalone.java:111)
    at br.com.xpto.sys.jobs.AppStandalone.main(AppStandalone.java:75)
```

Comment: How do you get an instance of the service? Post that code, and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @JBNizet Updated the post as requested. Thanks.

Comment: You are creating a `new TicketServiceImpl();` which is not a spring managed bean. Either you need to autowrie it or get it from service locator

Comment: This link will help you in creating a service locator https://objectpartners.com/2010/08/23/gaining-access-to-the-spring-context-in-non-spring-managed-classes/

Comment: If you instance your processor as a spring bean, you could simply autowire the TicketService as instance member. @Autowire TicketServiceImpl srv; As you saw in the logs, TicketServiceImpl is instantiated as a spring bean, but when you use "new" your create a new instance, not the one that is managed by the spring container.

Comment: Please post it as an answer, so I could close the topic.